# How to load themes from the database in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm going to have a single site that needs to be themed a number of ways.  I want to pull the theme information from a database to save from having to redeploy every time a new theme is needed.  I read you can create a custom ThemeSource implementation but was unsure how to implement a database driven theme source.  Anyone have experience with this in Spring MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple.

Spring Controller, no filter - controllers are easier to wire-up.

- Make the theme simple (one css file, one js file, a couple of images) it will help.
- Create a theme and themeresource table in the database. theme contains theme_id, theme_name, theme_description. themeresource contains resource_id, theme_id, name, content(blob). (I'd use Hibernate)
- Create a DAO for theme access (I'd use Hibernate)
- Create a controller called ThemeController. Map it to "/theme/resources".
- In the controller read the request, see what file it's requesting(ex: "/theme/resources/style.css").
- You already know what theme is required because of the ThemeResolver
- Serve the "style.css" file (and all other files) from the database by querying the DAO with the theme and the resource name

Another option would be to create a listener/filter that does exactly what the above controller should do.